# How to style wind direction and wind speed in geoserver style postgis?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, geoserver

I'm trying to create a style in geoerver to show wind driection and wind speed but im not getting accurate result the data is coming from postgis postgres db
attributes name (wind_dir, wind_speed)
here is the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd">

    <NamedLayer>
        <Name>Windy_wind_test</Name>
        <UserStyle>
            <Title>Wind Speed and Direction</Title>
            <FeatureTypeStyle>
                <Rule>
                    <PointSymbolizer>
                        <Graphic>
                            <Mark>
                                <WellKnownName>triangle</WellKnownName>
                                <Fill>
                                    <CssParameter name="fill">#6699FF</CssParameter> <!-- Light blue -->
                                </Fill>
                                <Stroke>
                                    <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter> <!-- Black -->
                                    <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</CssParameter>
                                </Stroke>
                            </Mark>
                            <Size>
                                <!-- Adjust size based on wind speed -->
                                <ogc:Mul>
                                    <ogc:PropertyName>wind_speed</ogc:PropertyName>
                                    <ogc:Literal>5</ogc:Literal> <!-- Adjust this multiplier as needed -->
                                </ogc:Mul>
                            </Size>
                            <Rotation>
                                <!-- Rotate the triangle based on wind direction -->
                                <ogc:PropertyName>wind_dir</ogc:PropertyName>
                            </Rotation>
                        </Graphic>
                    </PointSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
            </FeatureTypeStyle>
        </UserStyle>
    </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Comment: Do you know what "wind roses" (a type of wind plotting graph) are? google it.

Comment: what do you mean by "not getting [an] accurate result"? Have you looked at https://docs.geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/multidim/accessing_multidim/rtx/wind_barbs.html for a clue

Comment: #lan Turton using that style give me error unable to find function "ras:RasterAsPointCollection"